# Is it possible to get the mouse position only relative to your element

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, mousewheel, mouse-position

I have trouble to get the mouse position relative to the elements attached event if i have multiple children in given element.

```
domElement.addEventListener('wheel', event => {
 event.offsetX //x relative to target element
 event.offsetY //y relative to target element
}
```

If my mouse hovers a child element it gives the childs position. I am aware of event.pageX or event.clientX but it gives me the mouse position relative to the window/viewport.

```js
const element = document.getElementById("wrapper");
const output = document.getElementById("output");
element.addEventListener("wheel", event =>{
output.innerHTML = `offsetX: ${event.offsetX}, offsetY: ${event.offsetY}`;
});
```

```css
#wrapper{
  height:300px;
  width:500px;
  background:#ccc;
  position:absolute;
  left:400px;
  top:20px;
}

#child{
  position:relative;
  height:120px;
  width:130px;
  left:50px;
  top:120px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="child">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect
To get the position of the element, and then it's a simple operation.

Comment: Yeah +1. This is the solution that i found by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

If you set this CSS attribute to your child element:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

The wheel position will always be relative to the parent, but remember it will disable all mouse interactions with the child element.

You can find more info here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately I have to be able to use different mouse events inside my child element. Like 'click'-event

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which i do not really like. The function `getBoundingClientRect ()`.

```js
const element = document.getElementById("wrapper");
const output = document.getElementById("output");
element.addEventListener("wheel", event =>{
   let { x, y } = element.getBoundingClientRect();
   let position = { x, y };
   let mousex = event.clientX - position.x;
   let mousey = event.clientY - position.y;
output.innerHTML = `offsetX: ${mousex}, offsetY: ${mousey}`;
});
```

```css
#wrapper{
  height:300px;
  width:500px;
  background:#ccc;
  position:absolute;
  left:400px;
  top:20px;
}

#child{
  position:relative;
  height:120px;
  width:130px;
  left:50px;
  top:120px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="child">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="output"></div>
```